# How can function references be executed properly (1)?

Tags: javascript

`win` points to `window`.  `NS` is a temporary namespace for this post.  I thought that if I wanted access to `setTimeout`, I could just copy over the function reference as such:

```
NS.setTimeout = win.setTimeout;
```

However, execution will throw an error:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object @ ...
```

To fix this error, I just did:

```
NS.setTimeout = function (arg1, arg2) {
    return win.setTimeout(arg1, arg2);
};
```

However, I don't know why this fixed it.  I don't know what language mechanics are causing this behavior.

Comment: The assignment by itself would not cause such an error. I think your question is misstated. You must mean that **invoking** the assigned value raised the error.

Comment: I don't understand. setTimeout() is globally available, isn't it? Why do all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem b.c. you are changing the calling object back to the original when you call it.

```
return win.setTimeout(arg1, arg2);
```

will set the context ( or this ) back to window where it should be.  The other answers are similar in the fact that they change the context to the correct value using `bind` to `apply`.

Comment: You are a poet and a scholar sir!

Answer (score 8):

What you want is this :

```
NS.setTimeout = win.setTimeout.bind(win);
```

or what you already do, if you want to be compatible with IE8.

Because `setTimeout`, like many `window` functions, needs the receiver (`this`) to be `window`.

Another IE8 compatible solution, more elegant in my opinion than yours (because it doesn't use the fact you know the number of arguments needed by `setTimeout`), would be

```
NS.setTimeout = function(){
  return win.setTimeout.apply(win, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the result!

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you can't do that is because, when assigining, you're changeing the call context of `setTimeout`, which isn't allowed.
Nor is it allowed for `setInterval`, and many of the other native objects/functions. Again: a great rule of thumb: if you don't *own* the object, don't touch it. Since functions are objects in JS, that rule applies to them, too

[check the specs on the global object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15) and its properties/builtin funcitons:

> There are certain built-in objects available whenever an ECMAScript program begins execution. One, the global object, is part of the lexical environment of the executing program. Others are accessible as initial properties of the global object.

And so on. But [the lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2) is quite significant. By assigning a reference to the function elsewhere, you could well be masking part of the lexical environment, or exposing too much of the global environment (eg mashups).

Comment: this is not only specific to setTimeout.  I've seen this issue when copying over `console.log` as well. +1.

Comment: @Bill-TheButcher-Cutting: Edit made to my answer, but since dystroy was here first, best accept his answer

Comment: The "*the `this` problem*" section which you linked has nothing to do with the OPs problem.

Comment: Context is determined when the function is called. My impression was this is throwing an exception at the assignment which is not what I would have expected.  Unless they are not actually true javascript functions...

Comment: @Deadron: I'm checking the binding tests of ECMAScript ATM, but I have noticed this is a FF specific issue, chrome throws a TypeError (illegal invocation)