# How to properly map function constructors?

Tags: javascript

Me and Smurfette are mapping native functions over to a new smurfy namespace we call

```
SMURF
```

To to do this we make sure and map over the correct value of this as well, by calling the function from with in the correct context.  There are many ways to do this, but this is just one.

For example,

```
SMURF.getComputedStyle = function(){
  return win.getComputedStyle.apply(win, arguments);
};
```

However, how would this be done for OO style functions objects?  Particularly,

```
SMURF.FormData = win.FormData;
```

Can this be done in the same manner?

The calling mechanism is different, that is why we ask.

```
new SMURF.FormData();
```

as opposed to

```
SMURF.getComputedStyle();
```

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859838/how-can-function-references-be-copied-and-executed/17885196#17885196).

I guess the implied question, is can `apply` be used on function constructors?

**Clarification:**

Not concerned with Pre-IE9

Comment: Please remove all of this smurf nonsense (it's technically trademark infringement, and [they don't like that](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2005/11/08/smurf_domain_revenge/)).  On a more serious note, your question is confusing.  Please try rewriting it, and include what your expected results are.

Answer (score 2):

Well for non-generic methods that are implemented as methods of the window object, you can use `.bind` e.g.:

```
SMURF.setTimeout = setTimeout.bind(window);
```

If the method is generic or a constructor you can just do

```
SMURF.x = window.x
```

e.g.

```
SMURF.FormData = FormData;
```

will work just fine.

Note that in IE8 `.call` (and therefore also any `.bind` shim) cannot change context properly for host objects.

Comment: @smurfbrainy cool trolling, instead of thinking, why not try it (or alternatively, develop an understanding of the language)